# Batch file to remove carriage return (New Line)

Tags: shell, return, linefeed

I need help to take the line breaks from my text file.

example data:

```
mango apple grapes peanut
mango apple grapes peanut
mango apple grapes peanut
mango apple grapes peanut
```

desired output:

```
mango apple grapes peanut mango apple grapes peanut mango apple grapes peanut mango apple grapes peanut
```

It will only work if it is on one line.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 5):

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker

FOR /F "Usebackq Tokens=*" %%@ IN ("File.txt") DO (
    <NUL Set /P "=%%@"
)

Pause&Exit
```